# Error for createFromPdu that has deprecated

Tags: java, android

I am trying to receive SMS in an emulator. And this code is almost basic code that given by android API.
But there's an error in `createFromPdu((byte[]) objs[i], format);` code and err msg was `createFromPdu(byte[])` in SmsMessage cannot be applied to
       `(byte[], java.lang.String)`.
Then I searched it and `createFromPdu(byte[] pdu)` is deprecated and `createFromPdu(byte[] pdu, String format)` is available over 23.
But it has an error even though my **compilesdkversion** is 25.
Can somebody help me with this problem?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = "SmsReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive() method called.");

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;
        messages = parseSmsMessage(bundle);

        if( messages != null && messages.length > 0) {
            String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            Log.i(TAG, "SMS sender : " + sender);

            String contents = messages[0].getMessageBody().toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "SMS contents : " + contents);

            Date receivedDate = new Date(messages[0].getTimestampMillis());
            Log.i(TAG, "SMS received date : " + receivedDate.toString());
        }
    }

    private SmsMessage[] parseSmsMessage(Bundle bundle) {

        Object[] objs = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[objs.length];



        int smsCount = objs.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < smsCount; i++) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { // over API 23 
                String format = bundle.getString("format");
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(**(byte[]) objs[i], format**);
            } else {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) objs[i]);
            }
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: That kind of error in Android Studio ussually shows which are the expected parameter types and which are the found parameter types. It is very likely there is a missmatch in the type of the parameter.

Comment: no, but I checked in android API that second parameter is String.
So I think the parameter type isn't mismatched.

Comment: I pasted parseSmsMessage() into a project of mine and I don't get any errors. Can you post you gradle module file (ussually app module).

Comment: ok but I don't know how to post so here is copy & paste
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.androidtown.samplereceiver"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: Somewhere under your question you must have an edit link that lets you edit your question. There you can post aditional information like this one.

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle module you are compiling against api 25 but you are targetting api 22, if you change your taget to 25 your error should go away.

Comment: I have pasted the method into a project of mine and it doesn't show any error. The only difference is I removed the "**" which I guess were added when you tried to make the text bold here in StackOverflow.